# How to change Gridview Item UI when Observable Collection change object state

Tags: xaml, uwp

I'm trying to only allow one toggle button inside my gridview toggle on. If the next one toggled, the previous toggle button must be de-toggle. the structure of my gridview are these:

1. GridView bind with an observable collection
2. Inside a gridview content a user-control represent the gridview item

   ```
        <controls:AdaptiveGridView.ItemTemplate>
           <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:FoodDTO">
               <usercontrols:FoodCard FoodId="{x:Bind FoodId}" FoodName="{x:Bind FoodName}" FoodEnglishName="{x:Bind FoodEnglishName}" IsSelected="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                      MainFoodIcon="{x:Bind MainIcon}" SecondaryFoodIcon="{x:Bind SecondaryIcon}" ToggleClick="FoodCard_ToggleClick"/>
           </DataTemplate>
       </controls:AdaptiveGridView.ItemTemplate>
   ```
3. Here is the XAML of my User-Control

   ```
   <Grid Height="130" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="5" Padding="0">
   <ToolkitControls:DropShadowPanel x:Name="DropShadowHolder" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="10" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                          BlurRadius="20"
                          ShadowOpacity="0.5" OffsetX="1" OffsetY="20"
                          Color="Black">
       <Grid Background="{ThemeResource SystemAltHighColor}" Height="100" CornerRadius="5" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
         VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Padding="0">
           <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
               <ColumnDefinition Width="80"/>
               <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
           </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
           <ToggleButton Content="CHỌN" FontWeight="Bold" Click="ToggleButton_Click" IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"
                         VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="10,0,0,10" Width="70"  FontSize="12"/>
           <Grid Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="11">
               <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
                   <TextBlock Text="40%" />
                   <ProgressBar Height="30" CornerRadius="3" Value="40"/>
               </StackPanel>
               <PersonPicture Width="25" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,-10,0,0"/>
           </Grid>
           <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind FoodName, Mode=OneWay}" Grid.Column="1" Margin="6,0,0,0"
                  FontSize="15" />
       </Grid>
   </ToolkitControls:DropShadowPanel>
   <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
       <Grid Margin="20,0,0,0">
           <Image x:Name="MainFoodImage" Width="70" Height="70"                       
              VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
           <Image x:Name="SecondaryFoodImage" Width="20" Height="20"
              VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
       </Grid>
       <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind FoodEnglishName, Mode=OneWay}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="6,-5,0,0"
                  FontSize="15" FontWeight="Bold" />
   </StackPanel>
   ```
4. Here is the code behind of that UserControl

   public sealed partial class FoodCard : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
   {

   ```
   public int FoodId
   {
       get { return (int)GetValue(FoodIdProperty); }
       set { SetValue(FoodIdProperty, value); }
   }

   // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for FoodId.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
   public static readonly DependencyProperty FoodIdProperty =
       DependencyProperty.Register("FoodId", typeof(int), typeof(FoodCard), null);



   public string FoodName
   {
       get { return (string)GetValue(FoodNameProperty); }
       set { SetValue(FoodNameProperty, value); }
   }

   // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for FoodName.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
   public static readonly DependencyProperty FoodNameProperty =
       DependencyProperty.Register("FoodName", typeof(string), typeof(FoodCard), null);



   public string FoodEnglishName
   {
       get { return (string)GetValue(FoodEnglishNameProperty); }
       set { SetValue(FoodEnglishNameProperty, value); }
   }

   // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for FoodEnglishName.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
   public static readonly DependencyProperty FoodEnglishNameProperty =
       DependencyProperty.Register("FoodEnglishName", typeof(string), typeof(FoodCard), null);



   public bool IsSelected
   {
       get { return (bool)GetValue(IsSelectedProperty); }
       set { 
           SetValue(IsSelectedProperty, value);
           if (PropertyChanged != null)
           {
               PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("IsSelected"));
           }       
       }
   }

   // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for IsSelected.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
   public static readonly DependencyProperty IsSelectedProperty =
       DependencyProperty.Register("IsSelected", typeof(bool), typeof(FoodCard), new PropertyMetadata(null));


   public int MainFoodIcon
   {
       get { return (int)GetValue(MainFoodIconProperty); }
       set
       {
             SetValue(MainFoodIconProperty, value);
             MainFoodImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(_mainFoods[value]));
       }
   }

   // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for MainFoodIcon.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
   public static readonly DependencyProperty MainFoodIconProperty =
       DependencyProperty.Register("MainFoodIcon", typeof(int), typeof(FoodCard), null);





   public int? SecondaryFoodIcon
   {
       get { return (int?)GetValue(SecondaryFoodIconProperty); }
       set
       {
           if(value != null)
           {
               SetValue(SecondaryFoodIconProperty, value);
               SecondaryFoodImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(_secondaryFoods[value]));
           }
           else SecondaryFoodImage.Source = null;
       }
   }

   // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for SecondaryFoodIcon.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
   public static readonly DependencyProperty SecondaryFoodIconProperty =
       DependencyProperty.Register("SecondaryFoodIcon", typeof(int?), typeof(FoodCard), null);

   private readonly IDictionary<int, string> _mainFoods = new Dictionary<int, string>
   {
       { 1, "ms-appx:///Assets/FoodAssets/Rice.png"},
       { 2, "ms-appx:///Assets/FoodAssets/Bread.png"},
       { 3, "ms-appx:///Assets/FoodAssets/Spagheti.png"},
       { 4, "ms-appx:///Assets/FoodAssets/Noodle.png"},
       { 5, "ms-appx:///Assets/FoodAssets/LunchFood.png"}
   };

   private readonly IDictionary<int?, string> _secondaryFoods = new Dictionary<int?, string>
   {
       { 6, "ms-appx:///Assets/FoodAssets/Meat.png"},
       { 7, "ms-appx:///Assets/FoodAssets/Chicken.png"},
       { 8, "ms-appx:///Assets/FoodAssets/Egg.png"},
       { 9, "ms-appx:///Assets/FoodAssets/Shrimp.png"},
       { 10, "ms-appx:///Assets/FoodAssets/Falafel.png"}
   };

   public event FoodCardEventHandler ToggleClick;
   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
   protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
   {
       PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
   }
   public FoodCard()
   {
       this.InitializeComponent();
   }

   private void ToggleButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
       ToggleClick?.Invoke(FoodId);
   }
   ```

The dependency property that hook to the toggle button also enable **OnNotifyPropertyChanged**
in this code notice that I expose the `ToggleButton_Click` to let the Page that contain the gridview can handle the click. And here's how I handle it

```
        private void FoodCard_ToggleClick(int foodId)
    {
        foreach(FoodDTO dto in Foods)
        {
                dto.IsSelected = false;
        }
        foreach (FoodDTO dto in Foods)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(dto.IsSelected);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("-------------");
        }
    }
```

I watch the console they are all output IsSelected is False, but the Toggle Button on the ui element doesn't de-toggle. Here is the FoodDTO

```
    public class FoodDTO
{
    public int FoodId { get; set; }
    public string FoodName { get; set; }
    public string FoodEnglishName { get; set; }
    public int MainIcon { get; set; } = 5;
    public int? SecondaryIcon { get; set; }
    public decimal Percentage { get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason the UI does not react to the change in `IsSelected` property is that the `FoodDto` is a POCO, and does not implement `INotifyPropetyChanged`. If you make sure to raise `PropertyChanged` when `IsSelected` changes, it will be reflected in the `x:Bind` in the `DataTemplate` and will also then flow into your `UserControl`.